# Moving the search bar to be in menu bar

Tags: themes, search, headers

[Our website](http://marcopdx.com) is in the middle of a major overhaul.

We are using a custom search bar through our industry research tool (on the homepage right now at the very top) and I currently have it in the header theme file. Is there a way to adjust it so that it is in the social media links section on the right? I'm wanting it where the current magnifying glass icon is.

[This is what the code looks like right now](https://codeshare.io/5Abcv):

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Vogue
 */
global $woocommerce;
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="page" class="hfeed site <?php echo sanitize_html_class( get_theme_mod( 'vogue-slider-type' ) ); ?>">

    <?php get_template_part( '/templates/header/header-layout-one' ); ?>

    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( '/templates/slider/homepage-slider' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="site-container <?php echo ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) ? sanitize_html_class( 'content-no-sidebar' ) : sanitize_html_class( 'content-has-sidebar' ); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a child theme instead of editing Vogue files directly. If you edit the files directly, and someday you update the Vogue theme, it will overwrite all of your edits. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/

It looks like a file called "header-layout-one.php" is where you'll find the social media icons. To get the search box to float right, insert it in the div with class "site-topbar-right".

Comment: Weird... I'm not seeing that file in the actual wordpress editor. Would that be something I would have to use SSH to see?

Comment: I would recommend disabling the wp-admin editor and using SFTP instead. That will help you find file names faster and prevent other problems.

Often the editor lists files by a name rather than a filename - so for example it may be called "Header One" or something similar. Since it's not a free theme it's not something a person without access to the files could find for you.